# How to show type introspection in UML

Tags: python, uml, reflection

I'm modeling a part of Python/Qt GUI code which uses reflection to construct a collection of widgets, in a form. The code works like this:

1. There is a `Model` which has attributes of various types, including (but not limited to) `Foo` and `Bar`. These types have corresponding widget types to be used in the form (`FooWidget`, `BarWidget`).
2. `SmartForm` iterates over all attributes of `Model`. If an attribute's type appears in its `_TYPE_MAP`, it creates the corresponding widget (by calling the type stored in the map) and links it to the attribute of `Model`.

This is my diagram so far:

[image: UML class diagram of the code]

I have two questions about depicting this in UML.

1. Should I create relations between `SmartForm` and the attribute types (`Foo`, `Bar`) and if so, what kind? The only use of these types by `SmartForm` is a type check (by means of Python's `isinstance()`). It doesn't call nor create any of these objects.
2. Is the `<<use>>` relationship the most appropriate one to depict that `SmartForm` looks at the attributes of `Model` and their types?
3. Is the compose relationship the most appropriate between `SmartForm` and the widgets? I feel like in the end, after everything has been setup, this is correct because `SmartForm` owns these objects. But I could also use an `<<instantiate>>` relationship. Or maybe both, but I think that adds unnecessary complexity to the diagram.

Side note: IMO there's only a thin line between compose and aggregate in Python, due to how objects are passed and the underlying reference counting (ownership can shift at runtime).

Comment: If I'd want to draw a *complete* diagram and since the `SmartForm` must be aware of `Foo` and `Bar`, I would add an association between them. However it usually depends on what you want to communicate with the diagram. Maybe a note would already be sufficent to not clutter the diagram. Regarding your second point, how does the SmartForm parse the model? I assume it holds a reference so an association would be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

UML has no build-in support for introspection. In particular does not foresee the ability to pass the type as a parameter. You may consider the following alternatives:

1. **Extend UML metamodel**, to add a type type (not a typo!)  and other elements required for introspection.   You could think for example of a `«Introspection»` stereotype for the usage dependency that you currently have.
2. **Model a type representation**.  Make the python features used for introspection visible in your model or assume you could just bridge the gap.
3. **Use UML templates**, the only type mapping mechanism natively supported by UML: specific `Widget<Foo>`, `Widget<Bar>` or more generally `Widget<T>` would replace your `FooWidget` and the `_TYPE_MAP` (which should btw be static). Personally, I would see this as a very elegant approach that hides the implementation details. It allows however only one widget per type, and might mislead readers who see this as a rigid compile-time structure (even if the UML specs are agnostic in this regard).
4. **Focus on the design intent** and abstract even more the mapping.

Here dome details about this last option, that would allow to understand the logic but implement it also for languages not supporting introspection:

- `FooWidget` and `BarWidget` realise some general **`Widget`** interface (or if working with Python, an abstract class would do as well). We guess it currently through the naming, but interface realization would make it explicit.
- In view of the SRP / **separation of concerns**, make a distinction between the `SmartForm` construction and the form itself. For this purpose, you could use a **factory** for creating the `Widgets` based on the model (Widgets appear to be a good candidate for composite pattern in view of the object composition principle).
- The Model would be made of instances of an interface `ModelProperty`
- Highlight the `«Create»` or the **`«Instantiate»` dependency** to clarify that the widgets are created by the factory.
- No need to attach the `Foo/Bar` properties to the `Smartform` since it's an indirect association.
- Simplify the relationship between `XxxWidget` and `Xxx`  getting rid of aggragation (aggregation has no longer a defined semantic in UML, and this since over twenty years).
- Composition is ok as you did. But do put it only if the lifecycle control really matters.  if not go for a simple association.

The advantage of this design, is that it leaves out the implementation details.  In Python or Java, you coud use introspection,  but in C++ or Rust, you'd have to go for other alternatives. But the core idea of the design remains the same and is well explained.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Indeed!  Thanks, completed :-)